# No puedo mostrar PDF con PDFViewer

Tags: android, studio, libreria

estoy utilizando la **librería PDFViewer** para mostrar los PDFs dentro de la aplicación, pero me esta dando problemas, no se si es porque ya ha dejado de funcionar esta librería, o tengo alguno problema con Android Studio.

```
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer
```

La he estado utilizando sin problemas, pero hace ya un tiempo que por mas que pruebo me muestra el mismo error.
Implemento la librería sin problemas aparentes, pero en el xml ya me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que no me dejara generar la aplicación, pero la intento generar y este es el mensaje que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**build.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }  
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
     }
 }

 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }  
     }
 }
```

Sabe alguien donde esta el problema, o es que esta libreria a muerto :(

Gracias.

Comment: probablemente aun no este disponible la implementacion, prueba con una libreria disponible para su uso como esta: implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

Comment: Voy a sugerir que elimines de tu layout el pdfViewer,  ve a la pestaña builds y selecciona clean project. Una vez que lo hayas hecho y haya finalizado el progreso, vuelves a Builds y está vez le das a Rebuild. Con eso podemos saber si el implementation está fallando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En settings.gradle(Project Settings), en esta archivo falta agregar dentro de dependencyResolutionManagement agregar gradlePluginPortal(), deberia verse de la siguiente manera:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Con esta modificacion ya te lograra descargar la libreria de pdfviewer, tenia el mismo problema, con esto se dio solucion. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En tu `build.gradle` tienes que añadir el repositorio donde está esa librería

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:

https://jitpack.io/#barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/65b428250a

No está disponible la versión que estás usando 3.2.0-beta.1 , sólo existe hasta 3.1.0-beta.1. Además si ves los logs de builds no han sido satisfactorios. Quizá debas considerar usar otra librería.

Comment: Si, lo tengo puesto, voy a añadir ese dato en el primer post.

Comment: @SoCu he encontrado otras cosas, revisa el edit.

Comment: He probado con el link que pones, y pasa lo mismo, tambien he puesto la version 2.8.2 que es la estable, y nada, sigue el mismo problema, he probado con otras librerias, SkewPdfView, PdfViewPager, PDFBox, iText, VigerV2, MuPDF, y algunas despues de fallar he visto que ni existen, otras solo leen de la carpeta assets, y otras hay que utilizar botones para pasar de paginas, algo impensable cuando utilizas pdf con mas de 100 paginas, asi que ya no se que libreria probar pare que trabaje como la **PDFViewer** y pueda leer archivos de la memoria externa, y que los muestre dentro de la aplicacion

Comment: La he encontrado en [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1) pero no existe la 2.8.2, creo que la documentación de github y lo que realmente existe no tiene concordancia.

Comment: En Github si te informa que puedes instalar la 2.8.2, que es la versión estable, de todas formas tanto con una como con otra tengo esos problemas para cargar la librería, no se si alguien mas tiene este problema o sabe porque se produce y como solucionarlo :(